# Convert array in quotation marks to just an array

Tags: arrays, string, swift

I currently have a string, that's supposed to be an Array:

```
var content = "['A','B','C']"
//What I want -> var content = ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

I need to remove the quotation marks, so that it's just an Array, i.e. String to Array. How would one attempt that?

Comment: This looks like legal JSON syntax. If that's what you want, look at NSJSONSerialization. Otherwise you'll have to write your own parser. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSJSONSerialization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks similar to JSON syntax except that the single quotes should be double quotes.

Well then, let's just do that:

```
let source = "['A','B','C']"
```

Replace single quotes with double quotes:

```
let content = source.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("'", withString: "\"")
```

Then convert the String to NSData (becomes valid JSON):

```
guard let data = content.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) else { fatalError() }
```

Finally, convert the JSON data back to a Swift array of Strings:

```
guard let arrayOfStrings = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as? [String] else { fatalError() }
```

Result:

```
print(arrayOfStrings)
```

> ["A", "B", "C"]

```
print(arrayOfStrings[1])
```

> "B"

Comment: Be careful though: as other have already warned you, this is not stable because the Strings could *contain* single quotes. But the JSON part still remains the right answer to your issue, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a semi-hacky solution to your specific example.

```
let content = "['A','B','C']"
var characters = content.characters
characters.removeFirst(2) // Remove ['
characters.removeLast(2)  // Remove ']
let contentArray = String(characters).componentsSeparatedByString("','")
print(contentArray) // ["A", "B", "C"]
```

**Disclaimer/Warning:** 
This solution isn't robust as it expects your array to only contain objects wrapped in `'` characters. It will however work for any length of string (e.g. replacing `A` with `foo` will work).

If your actual content string is any more complex than what you have here then I would take Rob's advice and try JSON serialization (especially if this string comes from a place you don't control like the server).

Answer (score 0):

You could do this one:

```
let arr = content.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet (charactersInString: "['],")).filter({!$0.isEmpty})
```

**Explanation**:

- First, we split the string into an array based upon separators like: `[`, `'`, `,`, `]`
- We now have an array with some empty strings, we use `filter()` to remove them.
- And Voila !

**Warning**:

like @nebs' warning, carefull with this solution. If your string is composed by more complexe strings (ex: `"['Hello [buddy]', 'What's up?', 'This is a long text, or not?']"`), especially string composed with the separators, you will get an array that will not match with your expected result.